# Completed tensor product of algebras over finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of order $q = p^n$. It is known that

$$\mathbb F[[x_1]] \widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb F} \mathbb F[[x_2]] = \mathbb F[[x_1, x_2]].$$ Geometrically, this is the completed local ring at a smooth closed point of a $2$-dimensional scheme over $\mathbb F$.

Is there a similarly nice characterisation of
$$\mathbb F[[x_1]] \widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb F_p} \mathbb F[[x_2]]$$
in case $\mathbb F \neq \mathbb F_p$?

My guess is that this is the ring of power series $\sum_{(k_1, k_2) \in \mathbb N^2} a_{k_1, k_2} x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2}$ such that for each power series $f$ there exists a constant $c_f$ such that if $k_1 \geq c_f$ and $k_2 \geq c_f$, we have $a_{k_1, k_2} \in \mathbb F_p$.

Is this hunch correct? Is there a (somewhat) natural geometric interpretation of this ring?

Comment: @reuns I'd be happy to take $\mathbb F = \mathbb F_{p^2}$. The hat is supposed to denote the completed tensor product, in this case as $\mathbb F_p$-algebras.

Comment: What is "completed tensor product"

Comment: @reuns I'm using the definition in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU

Comment: Then instead of the ambiguous $\widehat{\otimes}$ use $\varprojlim_{n,m\to \infty} F[[x]]/(x^n) \otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p} F[[y]]/(y^m)$ which is unambiguous and towards the answer as $F[[x]]/(x^n) \otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p} F[[y]]/(y^m)\cong F[[x,y]]/(x^n,y^m)  \otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p} F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using associativity and commutativity of tensor product you get

$$\begin{eqnarray}F[[x]]/(x^n) \otimes_k F[[y]]/(y^m)&\cong& (F \otimes_k k[[x]]/(x^n)) \otimes_k (k[[y]]/(y^m) \otimes_k F)
\\
&\cong&F \otimes_k (k[[x]]/(x^n) \otimes_k k[[y]]/(y^m)) \otimes_k F
\\
&\cong& F \otimes_k k[[x,y]]/(x^n,y^m) \otimes_k F
\\ &\cong& F[[x,y]]/(x^n,y^m) \otimes_k F
\\ &\cong& (F \otimes_k F)[[x,y]]/(x^n,y^m)\end{eqnarray}
$$

So that
$$\varprojlim_{n,m\to \infty} F[[x]]/(x^n) \otimes_k F[[y]]/(y^m)\cong \varprojlim_{n,m\to \infty} (F \otimes_k F)[[x,y]]/(x^n,y^m)\cong 
 (F\otimes_k F)[[x,y]]$$